# How to draw nicely nested integrals?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, integral

I would like to draw nested integrals such as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{d}\!{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
x_0 = \int_{-1}^{1} g(t) \d t
\quad
x_1 = \int_{-\int_{-1}^1 g(\theta) \d \theta
}^{\int_{-1}^1 g(\theta) \d \theta
} g(t) \d t
\quad
x_2 = 
\int
_{\int_{-\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \d x}^{\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \d x} 
g(\theta) \d \theta}
^{\int_{-\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \d x}^{ \int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \d x} 
g(\theta) \d \theta} 
g(t) \d t
\]
\[
x_n = \text{how to draw in a understanding way?}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm wondering if there are nicer ways to display this complex construction and especially if there are ways to draw `x_n`.

I would like to try using integral symbols of various sizes: a very big one for the integral at the first level, big ones for the second level, smaller ones for the next level, etc. with possibly `\ddots` up to the last level.

### PS:

I don't want to be explicit for the definition of `x_n` because this construction is used in a test and it is up to the student to understand the mechanism.

This idea comes this image, [taken here](https://twitter.com/alexscheffelin/status/1336909191127027712?s=20):

[image]

Comment: I guess you lost a minus sign in the definition of $x_2$, since your integral gives $x_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Steven's answer, I came to something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{d}\!{#1}}}

\def\smallMinus{\text{\char`-}}

\newcommand{\bigint}[1]{\scalebox{#1}{$\displaystyle\int$}}

\def\AA{\bigint{2}_{\hspace{-5mm}-\!\BB}^{\BB} g(t) \d t}
\def\BB{\bigint{1.5}_{\hspace{-3mm}-\!\CC}^{\CC} g(\theta) \d \theta}
\def\CC{\bigint{1}_{\hspace{-2mm}-\!\DD}^{\DD} g(x) \hspace{-0.5pt} \d x}
\def\DD{{\textstyle\int}_{\smallMinus1}^{1} g(u) \hspace{-0.6pt} \d u}



\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
x_0 = \int_{-1}^{1} g(t) \d t
,
\quad
x_1 = \int_{-\int_{\smallMinus 1}^1 g(\theta) \d \theta
}^{\int_{\smallMinus 1}^1 g(\theta) \d \theta
} g(t) \d t
,
\quad
x_2 = 
\int
_{\int_{-\int_{\smallMinus1}^{1} g(x) \d x}^{\int_{\smallMinus1}^{1} g(x) \d x} 
g(\theta) \d \theta}
^{\int_{-\int_{\smallMinus1}^{1} g(x) \d x}^{ \int_{\smallMinus1}^{1} g(x) \d x} 
g(\theta) \d \theta} 
g(t) \d t,
\\
x_3 = \AA, \quad 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

One of the big problems I find in the OP's output is that the minus sign seems too big, especially in the script and script-script sizes.  Thus, for the duration of the equation, I make `-` active and redefine things this way, making the minus a squeezed text dash, this being the only change I made:

```
\def\z{\mkern-2mu}
\catcode`-=13
\def-{\text{\char`-}\z}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{d}\!{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\def\z{\mkern-2mu}
\catcode`-=13
\def-{\text{\char`-}\z}
x_0 = \int_{-1}^{1} g(t) \d t
\quad
x_1 = \int_{-\int_{-1}^1 g(\theta) \d \theta
}^{\int_{-1}^1 g(\theta) \d \theta
} g(t) \d t
\quad
x_2 = 
\int
_{\int_{-\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \d x}^{\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \d x} 
g(\theta) \d \theta}
^{\int_{-\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \d x}^{ \int_{-1}^{1} g(x) \d x} 
g(\theta) \d \theta} 
g(t) \d t
\]
\[
x_n = \text{how to draw in a understanding way?}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

zoom

[image]

If I take the squeeze notion to the *limit* (ha-ha, pun intended), with these changes:

```
\let\svint\int
\def\int{\!\svint}
\def\z{\mkern-1.5mu}
\catcode`-=13
\def-{\z\text{\char`-}\z}
```

I arrive at this:

[image]